# Firefox changes URL protocol from wss to https when sending a websocket upgrade HTTP request

Tags: node.js, firefox, browser, websocket, cross-browser

We are working on an express/react application which is using websockets through https to fetch the data and display it on the front end. The app is working as designed on every browser except Firefox. It turns out that Firefox resolves the Request URL to "https://example.url" instead of sending "wss://example.url", which is the default behavior that works on every other broser. This in turn causes problems on the server during load balancing, and the server simply returns a 404 http error code.

I have already tried editing the about:config page in firefox regarding websockets and urlbars, to no avail. (although that would not count as a solution, since we cannot force our clients to do the same)

**Is there a way to disable said behavior on Firefox or force it to use wss?**

We are using ws node.js websocket library on both server and client.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Seems like the only way to solve it is to update the load balancer parameters.

Comment: It turned out I was using the npm `ws` package which does not work in the browser, and I should have been using the `WebSocket` implementation supplied by the browser in my client-side code.